# Matches text inside brackets with Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have some text like:

```
name:  [my_name]
email: [my_email]
```

I'd like to grab the fields in square brackets with regex—how would I do that?
I've tried using this pattern: `[*.?]`

Unfortunately it doesn't work. PHP gives this error:

```
compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0
```

What's wrong? Is the pattern correct?

Answer (score 3):

The brackets are special characters in regex.  To match them you'll have to escape them with a back-slash.  Something like `\[(.*?)\]`.  Adding the parens `()` captures whatever is matched inside it so you you can use it later.  Otherwise you're just matching on the whole pattern and you'd have to manually strip the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the * and escape the [ and ]. So make it `\[.*\]` Since . matches any character already and * says: 0 or more of that char. So .* is 0 or more of any char

Comment: What? Wouldn't that just match [a] and [] but not [foo] ?

Comment: @x3ro Already edited it before you even pressed "Add Comment". I noticed it myself ;)

Comment: I think you meant to say \\[.*?\\], otherwise, you are only matching one optional character.  To get 0 or more use .* for one or more use .+ which would make the pattern \\[.+?\\]

Answer (score 1):

No, you got the order wrong. It should be something like

```
\[(.*)\]
```

.* = Something repeated as many times as possible.

The compilation error you get is because the compiler does not now what to repeat, as [ is a special character in regular expressions. The `?` you added would also allow nothing within the brackets, which I figured you don't want, so I removed it. The question mark makes the foregoing statement optional. The parentheses aroudn the `.*` are used to capture the result. If you don't add those, the regex will match, but you won't get whats inside the brackets as result.

Comment: i'm using exactly the pattern u told me: $pattern = '\[(.*)\]';
but getting that error: "delimiter must not be backslash or alphanumeric" .. :(

Comment: You need to enclose all pattern with a delimiter when using perl regular expressions (preg_* functions). Normally a `/` is used, for example preg_replace('/\[(.*)\]/', ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text =
"name:  [my_name]
email: [my_email]";

$pattern = '/\[(.*)\]/';
$matches = array();

preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

$name = $matches[1][0];
$email = $matches[1][1];

print "$name<br />";
print "$email";
?>
```

will output

```
my_name
my_email
```

`/` is the delimiter (not part of the actual pattern per se). The `\` is for escaping the `[` and `]` brackets, as they define *character class definitions* in patterns when not escaped. `(` and `)` define subpatterns, which means that text captured by a subpattern will be put into the array referenced by the third parameter of `preg_match_all` (in this case `$matches`).

Answer (score 0):

### Escape it!

`[` and `]` special characters, so you need to escape them:

```
\[*.?\]
```